# @ManyToOne JPA spring mysql insert error, column null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Starting to get into spring boot and using the jpa repository to persist a  local mysql db and I  am having trouble with my insert. I simplified it to my user and task classes,  a user can have a task and i'm using the @ManyToOne annotation in the task classes for one directional  mapping. When the endpoint is called in post man I am getting an error and the trace is saying that the user_id column is null (which is the mapped column from user).

To debug I set a breakpoint in the service class of task on the actual taskRepo.save(task) method and it appears that the user_id is actually. I tried bidirectional mappings with one to many and many to one with mapped by option with no avail.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique = true)
private Long id;

private Long postId;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String username;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;





@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "taskName", nullable = false)
private String taskName;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;






@Autowired
private TaskService taskService;

@GetMapping("/getAllTask")
public List<Task> getAllTasks(){
    return taskService.getAllTask();
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@PostMapping("/addTask")
public void addTask(@RequestBody Task task){
    taskService.addTask(task);
}



@Autowired
private TaskRepo taskRepo;

public List<Task> getAllTask(){
    List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    taskRepo.findAll().forEach(task -> tasks.add(task));
    return tasks;
}

public void addTask(Task task){
    taskRepo.save(task);
}







{
        "taskName": "Task 1",
        "description": "This is the first item",
        "user_id": 1
    }



{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-02T02:15:06.989+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/task/addTask"
}

[enter image description here][1] ERROR 30016 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'user_id' cannot be null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is formatted incorrectly. `user_id` is not a field of `Task`.

Your json should look like this:

```
{
  "taskName": "Task 1",
  "description": "This is the first item",
  "user": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

The `user` json field is referring to

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

And because `User` is an object, it needs to be represented as an `JsonObject`.